# error: a character string failed conversation to a numeric value

Tags: teradata

I have a Teradata table in tableau.
When I am trying to give

```
select * from table name where date = <parameter.date selector>
```

I see the error as

> a character string failed conversation to a numeric value

Can someone assist me in solving this?

Comment: Can you show your actual `WHERE-condition`?

Comment: where date = '2018-12-31'; where date = '2018/12/31'; <- these two default formats would work (wrapped in quotes).